# c# collapse array list

Tags: c#, arraylist, mapping

if i have

```
class foo
{ 
   int a
   int b
}
```

and a `List<foo> myList`

is there some short hand notation for to make a `List<int> from eg myList[*].a`, ie pick out `a` from each element and making a new list

clearly this can be done by iterating through myList, but seems to happen often and i was wondering if there's a shortcut notation

same question for array etc

thanks

Comment: There's probably a duplicate target for this somewhere, but I don't know it, and don't know where to find it :/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using the C# 3.0 or higher compiler (VS2008 or up), try the following

```
List<Foo> list = GetTheList();
List<int> other = list.Select(x => x.a).ToList();
```